# Does the JIT compiler utilize long-term memory to keep track of optimized methods?

Tags: java, jboss, jit, quartz

I have an enterprise application that's running on JBoss 6.4 and I'm using quartz for job management, In short, I have over 6000 `Trigger`s that are being pulled from the database, updated, and then persisted again whenever I update the `Calendar`.

At first, it took quite a while to execute this method because of the huge number of `Trigger`s (about 45min) but then it began to decrease as I used the method more often until it reached 5 min, I thought it must be the JIT compiler in the JVM that is responsible for this but then I tried to kill the server and relaunch the app to clear the code cache of the JIT compiler but the time wasn't back to it's original on the contrary it decreased even more and reached the 2min range.

So I want to know does JIT keeps track of the optimized methods and save them on disk to not lose them when the JVM goes through a forced shutdown and if so how can I reset it to its original behavior?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

My environment looks like this:

JDK 1.8
MYSQL DB 5.7
JBOSS 6.4

Comment: There are many variables to consider. JVM version, .class files version, boot parameters.
I suggest looking into JVM CDS, Class Data Sharing, which received many new additions  and improvements lately.

Comment: The JVM does not do this by default.  To make that happen, you have to work for it.

Comment: It seems more likely the optimisation in speed is due to the nature of your database server access, not JVM. The second run speed-up is probably because of re-using statement level / other database caches.